# Radial symmetry of minimizer of functional of area.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

> Consider the functional of area for graphs as
> $$
> A(u)=\int_{A(r,R)}\sqrt{1+|Du|^2}dx,
> $$
> where $ A(r,R)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:r<|x|<R\} $. Consider the minimizer $ u $ of $ A $ in
> $$
> \operatorname{Lip}(A(r,R))=\{u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}:u\text{ is a Lipschitz function}\}.
> $$
> Show that $ u $ is radial symmetric in $ B(0,R) $.

I try to show that
$$
A(\overline u)<A(u),
$$
where
$$ 
\overline{u}(r)=\frac{1}{\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(S^{n-1})}\int_{S^{n-1}}u(r,\theta)d\theta.
$$
But I cannot continue. Can you give me some references or hints?